# How to set up Nginx proxy

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, nginx-config

I have some problems with setting the Nginx proxy. I hope it works like the below example.

```
Http or Https call(http://example.com/api/user/info)
-> Nginx(/api location work for proxy) 
-> Spring boot(http://example.com:8443/user/info)

But it goes to http://example.com:8443/api/user/info.
```

Please help me.

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass         http://example.com:8443;

    proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    http;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size                0;

    proxy_connect_timeout                   150;
    proxy_send_timeout                      100;
    proxy_read_timeout                      100;

    proxy_buffer_size                       8k;
    proxy_buffers                           4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size                 64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size              64k;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with trailing slash

like below:-

```
proxy_pass http://example.com:8443/;
```